# Magnetizing Inductor vs Transformer

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, inductor, flyback

I am a bit confused by the diagram - are there two inductors in parallel on the primary side of the flyback transformer?

How does no current flow through v1 when the switch is closed?

[image]

Comment: .What was drawn like that cannot work. The current for the coupled inductance must also be switched on the primary side

Comment: The leakage inductor is outside to simulate what was lost or not coupled to secondary

Comment: It's most important on this question that you do provide a link to the original place where the diagram came from.

Answer (score 5):

There is an endless debate about the flyback converter regarding the primary-to-secondary transfer mechanism: transformer or coupled inductors? When you look at the magnetic structure, it certainly looks like a transformer but in the simplified view, there is no current simultaneously circulating in the primary *and* the secondary.

Look at the below picture, excerpted from my seminar *[The Dark Side of the Flyback Converter](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202011.pdf)*:

[image]

When the main switch closes, the input voltage is applied across the primary side and a current circulates: the primary-side inductance magnetizes and stores energy. The current "enters" the transformer by the dot and would like to "leave" by the opposite dot. However, the reverse-biased diode forbids this to happen and the secondary is decoupled from the primary side during this moment: there is no current circulation in the secondary.

When the PWM controller instructs the switch to open - because the peak current has reached the setpoint for instance - then the magnetic field inside the core collapses and the voltage across the magnetizing inductance reverses in an attempt to keep the amperes-turns. The secondary diode now conducts with a current and the energy stored in the primary feeds the output capacitor and the load. The secondary current at this moment is the primary peak current at the switch opening scaled by the transformer turns ratio:

[image]

The output voltage \$V_{out}\$ now appears across the secondary winding (because the diode conducts) but it also *flies back* to the primary side scaled by the turns ratio. The voltage on the blocked transistor during this time is thus the input source plus the reflected voltage. In reality, the switching mechanisms are more complicated (there are parasitics such as the leakage inductance, the various capacitances etc.) and, during the transitions, a current certainly circulates in the primary and the secondary at the same time during a short moment. You can find details about all these effects in my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071823468) on power supplies.

Comment: -- Just a question about slide 44, EMI radiation. In my younger years, I saw an "article" on how to assemble "transistor and radiator" so as not to emit interference to "the outside" but to "short-circuit" it to the ground. I think by inserting a special additional "shield". but impossible to find this article ... Do you something as this ?

Comment: Perhaps figure 2 of this [document](https://www.emcstandards.co.uk/files/emc_techniques_for_heatsinks_july_2010.pdf) will answer your question?

Comment: Very fine ! Thanks. Fig 9 & 10 ...

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I always learn something new from your posts. One quick question, though. If the diode wasn't there, would the coupled inductor behave as a "transformer" in the sense that it will transfer power to the secondary right away?

Comment: @Big6, hello, oui, if the diode wasn't there to block, then you would have currents simultaneously circulating in the primary and secondary sides. Thanks for the kind words, I always try to bring some modest scientific substance rather than just quickly answering without details.

Comment: @VerbalKint I have a question regarding the coupled inductor. When is the switch turned off then will there be any practical current flowing in the primary??? Practically we don't have two inductors in parallel as shown at the primary side in the question, so no current should flow??? The diagram in the question shows a loop forming between the LM and the coupled inductor at primary, and It can be seen diagrammatically that current can flow in the loop. But How is this practically observed when we just have one single primary winding and nothing parallel???? plz help.

Comment: @kam1212, please look at slide 29 of my [seminar](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202011.pdf) where you see that, at turn off, the leakage inductance diverts the energy stored in the magnetizing inductance, implying zero current in the secondary and zero also in the primary for a fraction of time. Keep in mind that this is a model and you cannot directly observe the magnetizing current unless you reconstruct it.